# Azure DevOps Pipeline dotnet ef migrations fails with local artifacts

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-pipelines

My Azure DevOps Pipeline needs to access some NuGet packages stored in Azure DevOps Artifacts feed.

The package source artifact is defined in `<packageSources>` of `nuget.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="xxx" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xxx/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

The dotnet restore works because of the `vstsFeed` input:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

The `dotnet publish` goes in `401` when access to the Artifacts feed. So I follow the hint from https://stackoverflow.com/a/57263923 and added the `--no-restore` parameter.
Now it works:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) --no-restore'
    zipAfterPublish: True
```

But now the `dotnet ef migrations` do not works: `build failed`.

YAML:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --startup-project xxx/xxx.Portal/xxx.Portal.csproj --project xxx/xxx.Core/xxx.Core.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SQL/migrate.sql --context Dbxxx --idempotent'
```

I tried with `--no-build` ...:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --no-build --startup-project xxx/xxx.Portal/xxx.Portal.csproj --project xxx/xxx.Core/xxx.Core.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SQL/migrate.sql --context Dbxxx --idempotent'
```

... but another error come:

```
The specified deps.json [D:\a\1\s\xxx\xxx.Portal\bin\Debug\net5.0\xxx.Portal.deps.json] does not exist
```

Also adding the `feedsToUse` and `vstsFeed` inputs changes nothing:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --startup-project xxx/xxx.Portal/xxx.Portal.csproj --project xxx/xxx.Core/xxx.Core.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SQL/migrate.sql --context Dbxxx --idempotent'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: Could you try adding a dotnet task to run build command to build the project before the dotnet task executing dotnet ef migrations with `--no-build`?

Comment: Now it works. I had to add 2 tasks: nuget restore & build with --no-restore. Thanks!!! Now I will try to rationalize YAML because I have double tasks.

Comment: That's great you fixed it. You share the fix in the answer thread in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the Levi Lu-MSFT comment I've fixed my YAML adding 2 tasks before the `ef migrations` one.

Because Azure DevOps do not allow user to specify the authorization to access the private Azure DevOps Artifacts Feed on the `restore` operation in `build` and `ef migrations` tasks, the correct sequence is:

1. `restore` task with authorization by `feedsToUser` and `vstsFeed`
2. `build` task with `--no-restore` parameter
3. `ef migrations` task with `--no-build` parameter

So the complete YAML is:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'xxx/xxx.Portal'
    arguments: '--no-restore'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'ef'
    arguments: 'migrations script --no-build --startup-project xxx/xxx.Portal/xxx.Portal.csproj --project xxx/xxx.Core/xxx.Core.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SQL/migrate.sql --context Dbxxx --idempotent'
```